# Using AngularJS for UI and ASP.NET WebAPI services running on same Grunt webserver?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, gruntjs

I am developing **MVC WebAPI** developing with VisualStudio.
I love it!

I started developing **UI with AngularJS** with the help of Yeoman. Using "Grunt serve" to run a nodejs webserver.

I love it too!

Especially the file monitoring and the immediate refresh of the browser is nice.

**Here is my issue**
Requests to the Webapi are **cross domain** cause angularjs is running on port **localhost:9000** while webapi is on **localhost in IIS**. I used the CORS settings so I do not get an error, but still...

Is there a way I could easily **run Webapi and AngularJS on the same localhost webserver** yet keeping the magnificent auto-refresh feature i have when using "grunt serve"?

Please also let me know if this is totally silly. thanks :-)

Comment: Yes you can, it basically consists on including your client side angular into your mvc webapi app (through a root mapper controller), this will make them run on same host. Now if you want the autorefresh feature, you'll have to tweak your gruntfile and understand how the watch task works. NB: you'll still have to use grunt aside of VS for the autorefresh to work.

Comment: have you been able to make this work? I am looking for the exactly the same answer.  Thanks!